# Not able to build qt5 in release

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm buiding QT 5 with Visual Studio 2010 because i need to have debug symbols.
I use the following commands:

```
configure -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -platform win32-msvc2010 -opensource -mp
nmake
```

But it seems that QT was built only in debug mode, because i can see only *d.dll files in qtbase/bin and qtbase/lib folders.

When i try to build sample qt project, it goes ok in debug.
But in release i get the following error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'qtmain.lib'
```

This file is indeed absent in my QT folder.

I also tried "-release" instead of "-debug-and-release" and it also created debug libraries instead of release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build Qt5.0.2 with `configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests`

In detail:

1. Install strawbey perl (http://strawberryperl.com/)
2. Install Windows SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa904949 even when you are using Windows 7.  On older versions of Microsoft Windows the DirectX SDK should be installed.
3. Download Qt 5.0.2 source code from http://qt-project.org/downloads
4. Start “Open VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt“
5. Make sure that python is available on the command prompt. When installing Python you can add python.exe to the environment path. (I used python 3.3)
6. Switch to Qt 5.0.2 source directory (directory which contains configure.bat)
7. Run configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
8. and afterwards
   nmake

Answer (score 1):

Here [(How To Compile Qt with Visual Studio)](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/) is a guide for building Qt on VS2010. In the comments to that article, there are instructions for building Qt 5, [here](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/#comment-7546).